# Can I send email from an account on same domain but different than SMTP logged account using PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, email

My question is simple. On wordpress, want to make a custom form and send emails using SMTP auth.

Can I log on SMTP server with, for example, foo@test.com and send emails from bar@test.com? Or emails can only be sent by logged account, in this case, foo@test.com?

Thanks,

Comment: In my experience, that's possible. In my experience too, however, is that the sent emails will quickly be flagged as spam because the email address is unresolvable and your entire domain might end up blacklisted. This doesn't have to happen, but it did to me a couple of times.

Comment: Yes, You can send. Your SMTP server Auth user email is different and your send email is also different.

Comment: It depends on the policy configured in the MTA - nothing to do with Wordpress nor PHP.